# append array with <ul class="deck">

Tags: jquery

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with for statement. Whether the format for inserting semicolon as text/string is correct?

```
const cardList=["diamond", "fpaper-plane-o", "anchor","bolt","cube","anchor","leaf","bicycle","diamond","bomb","leaf","bomb","bolt","bicycle","paper-plane-o","cube"];

for( let i=0; i<=length; i++){
  jQuery('.deck')('<li class="card"><i class="fa fa-' + cardList[i] + '"></i></li>');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a syntax error:

```
jQuery('.deck')('<li class="card"><i class="fa fa-' + cardList[i] + '"></i></li>');
//------------^^
```

You have to use the `.append()` function here:

```
jQuery('.deck').append('<li class="card"><i class="fa fa-' + cardList[i] + '"></i></li>');
```

**Snippet**

```js
const cardList = ["diamond", "paper-plane-o", "anchor", "bolt", "cube", "anchor", "leaf", "bicycle", "diamond", "bomb", "leaf", "bomb", "bolt", "bicycle", "paper-plane-o", "cube"];

for (let i = 0; i < cardList.length; i++) {
  jQuery('.deck').append('<li class="card"><i class="fa fa-' + cardList[i] + '"></i></li>');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="deck"></ul>
```

**Some more changes:**

- Your `for` loop variables and conditions are wrong.
- One of the icon class was wrong.